# Jetbrains 0xDBE : How can I load a SQL Server .bak file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

I'm trying this new Jetbrains IDE and I can't figure out how to load a SQL Server 2008 R2 .bak file. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong menus. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An IDE is not going to be able to "load" a SQL Server backup. You need to restore the backup to a running instance of SQL Server, then the IDE will be able to connect to it and interact with it. You should be able to connect the IDE to a running instance of SQL Server, and then through a query window run a `RESTORE` command, documented here:

- [`RESTORE` (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx)

Depending on where the backup came from, you will likely need to use the `WITH MOVE` options, as it is unlikely your default data/log folders match those from the source.

Comment: I thought could be possible because I can load bak's with 3rd party tools like https://sqlbackupandftp.com/restore/ . But I guess in this case you should be right.

Comment: @Knomo That product still needs a running SQL Server instance to restore to; it doesn't just open the backup file as if it were a database.